# I have problem with the unpack function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, unpack

excuse me because my englisch is not good.

I am a tring to decode somme binary messages with unpack in python. but i have a problem

the first message look like this

```
from struct import *
firstMessage = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00' #without tags
decodeFirstMessage = unpack('1q',firstMessage)
print(decodeFirstMessage[0])
```

the second message look like this

```
from struct import *
secondMessage = b'*xxyyzz \x03 \x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00 tago1;' #with tags
decodeSecondMessage = unpack('7s1s1B1sq1s6s',firstMessage)
print(decodeSecondMessage [0])
```

for the first code i get :

> 72057589742960640

as answer.

for the second code i get:

> unpack requires a buffer of 31 bytes

as answer.

i have tried to verify the value of format in the function unpack with this code

```
print(calcsize('1q'))
print(calcsize('7s1s1B1sq1s6s'))
```

i get:

> 8

and

> 31

I calculated the bytes myself and get

> 8

and

> 25

when i change q with b or h in "format" i get the correct value of 18 Bytes or 19 bytes with calcsize()

but for l and q i have problem

what ist wrong in my function or how can is solve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is padding.

Read the whole doc section [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

An example:

```
>>> print(calcsize('1s1q'))
16
>>> print(calcsize('=1s1q'))
9
```

Answer (score 0):

The short version is, use this for format instead:

```
"=7s1s1B1s1q1s6s"
```

The longer version is, [alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). When using default `@` meaning "native" for "Byte order", "Size", and "Alignment". The format is interpreted to match what layout of corresponding C `struct` on the platform would be. Using `=` the format switches to standard sizes and turns of alignment.